# Laravel how many rows inserted in an insert query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, count, insert

I have this query eloquent in `Laravel`, I was curious to know. If there is a way to know how many records inserted or how many records ignored to the table?

```
DB::table('mytable')->insertOrIgnore($data)
```

Note: One of the manual ways can be, counting records of table before and after process. but this has performance effect, if there be any better way achieving this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `insertOrIgnore()` returns the affected rows.

```
/**
 * Insert a new record into the database while ignoring errors.
 *
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return int
 */
public function insertOrIgnore(array $values) {
```

So you can simply use the returned value and compare it to what was expected to be inserted:

```
$affected = DB::table('mytable')->insertOrIgnore($data);
$ignored = count($data) - $affected;
```